# What is good word to describe the emotion of bliss combined with exhaustion after recovering from illness?

Tags: single-word-requests

In the early stage of infection and also during various stages of other illnesses one normally experiences the emotion that is quite nicely expressed as **malaise**, meaning a general uncomfort in your entire body, usually interpreted as "something is not right with me". After a succesful fight against infection your body enters a **different state characterized by a deep sense of calm, nearly bliss, but normally accompanied by fatigue** and the wish to sleep and rest. The dreams during this second stage are quite blissful, but not easily remembered, whereas the dreams during malaise may be quite disturbing, wild, fast-paced and demanding. The scenes of dreams during feverish malaise sleep tend to stick in consciousness which makes them easier to remember, even though they make notoriously little sense, which makes remembering them rather unappealing. Usually one remembers most the stark contrast between stormy waves and mirror-like surface of the sea when no wind has blown over it for weeks.

What is a fitting word for this post infection stage, similar to the way malaise manages to describe the first stage so well?

I remember a scene from the fellowship of the ring LOTR movie that captures this emotion quite well in images: https://youtu.be/tw-gCzBsAFI especially the first few seconds.

An example sentence could be:
When I woke up that morning after my fever chills the malaise had disappeared. In it’s place a feeling of [insert word here] had stepped: my body was suddenly at ease, but I was still very weak.

Creative ideas including poetic expression is welcome. Ideally it would just be one word though. I hope such a word exists!

Comment: something along the line of felicity (a state of happiness)?

Comment: "....This feeling or emotion is called... [insert word here]."  is not what we would call an example sentence where the word would be used.

Comment: Sorry, i hope it’s acceptable now.

Comment: Been there, done that.  Don't have a word for it, though, beyond "bliss".